# Case sensitive aes_decrypt query

Tags: mysql, aes

I have created an encrypted table. I am trying to search the table for a specific string regardless of the case but I cannot get it to work

String to search ( Staff )

```
select aes_decrypt(category, 'salt') from testtable where aes_decrypt(category, 'salt') like 'Staff'
```

The above query works

```
select aes_decrypt(category, 'salt') from testtable where aes_decrypt(category, 'salt') like 'staff'
```

The above query does not work. How can I search for 'staff' regardless of the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting the value to latin1 solved the case sensitive search.

```
select aes_decrypt(category, 'salt') from testtable where convert(aes_decrypt(category, 'salt') using latin1) like 'staff'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the results of your decryption give you a binary string, which is going to cause case sensitivity in compares.

You could:

```
select aes_decrypt(category, 'salt') 
from testtable 
where LOWER(aes_decrypt(category, 'salt') ) like LOWER('staff')
```

A more elegant solution would be to use `collate` as described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html).